# Naming convention for iOS

Tags: programming-languages

I am learning Objective-C and iOS development and not sure what proper naming convention should be used. I understand how to use the label aspect of Obj-C methods but not the proper way to name each label. What is the best practice for naming methods, properties, objects, outlets, and actions?

Also,
Should different naming conventions be used between Obj-C code and C code? And if so what differences is there?

Comment: Have you seen Apple's documentation? I am pretty sure they have everything listed out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aside from the official Apple [guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html), this [guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/objcguide.xml) from Google of all places should help you. For future reference, use the words "idiomatic" and whatever language you need to find stuff.

In quick summary:

Names should be descriptive, not abbreviations, contain the proper prefixes (NS, AB, IB, etc) where applicable, unambiguous, non-self referential and PascalCase.

Comment: Thank you for the good resources. I did not know Google themselves had such a great resource for programmers. I hadn't looked into the apple docs mainly due to liking examples to reference and what I have seen of apple docs examples are limited.